# HTML5 image list

Tags: html, markup

I'd like to create a list of book covers with their titles as a menu entry to point to book detail pages. Visually, it would be something like this:

```
+-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+
|     | |     | |     | |     |
|     | |     | |     | |     |
|     | |     | |     | |     |
|     | |     | |     | |     |
+-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+
Title 1 Title 2 Title 3 Title 4

+-----+ +-----+
|     | |     |
|     | |     |
|     | |     |
|     | |     |
+-----+ +-----+
Title 5 Title 6
```

I'm looking for the most neat html structure: I don't know if I should use float figure elements, or an unordered list, or something else. What would you recommend?

Thanks!

Comment: Personally, for tabular or grid data I would use a <table>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="" alt="" />
      <figcaption>IMG title</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <!-- more li's -->
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, that might be the way to do it. However, note that just because we have a bunch of new tags, does not mean that we must use them. What I mean, is that if the element can be presented without the use of the `figure`-tag, that would be preferred. What I usually think is "if this was non-HTML5, would I wrap the elements  in a `div` instead?". It depends on how the content is presented visually.

Comment: It's better for semantics, SEO, screen readers and in that particular case they might actually be useful, to do proper aligning, spacing and  (probably) add not mentioned elements. But still, your note about not overusing **new** tags is 100% valid :)

Answer (score 1):

You answer your own question:

> I'd like to create **a list** of book covers

;-)

An unordered list would make sense. You could also simply make a loop of floated `div`s, or maybe even `figure`. Here's what the spec has to say about the figure element:

> The figure element represents a unit of content, optionally with a caption, that is self-contained, that is typically referenced as a single unit from the main flow of the document, and that can be moved away from the main flow of the document without affecting the document’s meaning.

It depends on the overall structure of the document, and what part the elements play.